# How to 'deep-merge' dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

Imagine the following dicts:

```
a = {'key1': {'subkey1': [1, 2, 3]}}
b = {'key1': {'subkey2': [1, 2, 3]}}
```

I'd like to merge them to get

```
c = {'key1': {'subkey1': [1, 2, 3],
              'subkey2': [1, 2, 3]}}
```

Extra nice would be a solution that returns deep-copies from `a` and `b` which I can alter without altering `a` or `b`.

```
c = {**a, **b}
```

looks nice but seems to be the same as `c = copy(a).update(b)` which returns same as `b` in my case because `key1` gets overwritten by the update.

You can of course do this by hand like this (found in another answer):

```
def combine_dict(map1: dict, map2: dict):
    def update(d: dict, u: dict):
        for k, v in u.items():
            if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
                r = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
                d[k] = r
            else:
                d[k] = u[k]
        return d
    _result = {}
    update(_result, map1)
    update(_result, map2)
    return _result
```

But we have Python 3.5 now - maybe things have changed?

Comment: Nope, pretty much the same. As i know. And we almost have Python 3.6 btw.

Comment: I think it's fairly unlikely Python will ever have a built-in dictionary merge function, since how such an operation would work can vary — for example `dict.update()` just does one certain kind of "merging" because it simply replaces values of like-named keys.

Comment: @martineau I think most people would consider something that loses data to not be a merge

Comment: @mikemaccana: That's my point. The term "merge" means combine or blend, but not how it's done (nor whether any information is lost in the process).

Comment: @martineau OK. I believe most people would disagree with that meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You need recursion to accomplish this. Luckily [milanboers on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/milanboers/a8bb8b81b1c3fb3eb86ee2d9ea4bd5b2) saved us from hours of work and possible brain damage.

```
def deep_merge(dict1: dict, dict2: dict) -> dict:
    """ Merges two dicts. If keys are conflicting, dict2 is preferred. """
    def _val(v1, v2):
        if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
            return deep_merge(v1, v2)
        return v2 or v1
    return {k: _val(dict1.get(k), dict2.get(k)) for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}


a = {'key1': {'subkey1': [1, 2, 3]}}
b = {'key1': {'subkey2': [1, 2, 3]}}

a = deep_merge(a, b)
print(a)
```

Results in:

```
{'key1': {'subkey2': [1, 2, 3], 'subkey1': [1, 2, 3]}}
```